# Is it possible to make a video input to monitor Security system?

Tags: remote, rdp

I have a security system that has more features available if I hook up a monitor, mouse and keyboard directly to the system. But I Have to go upstairs and have all this hooked up all the time.

If possible how could I make a Raspberry Pi to act like a monitor and mouse and allow me to remote from another location and be as if I were right in front of the security system?

Comment: There are various wireless mice & keyboards, and monitor also apparently, based on a quick googling. I don't think Raspberry would be very helpful here. But what you probably want to have is a local network connecting your normal PC and the security system, so that it is a cable not radio.

Comment: I think what you'er looking for is KVM over IP (keyboard,video, mouse over IP). Eg https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=81002 or https://hackaday.io/project/7280-rasky-raspberry-pi-2-kvm-over-ip  The problem is you need a VGA video capture (which isn't particularly cheap) which works on RaspPi (which isn't particularly well-supported with drivers). If you do have local cable then you can get KVM over Cat5 quite cheaply

Comment: Yes, that is kind of what I'm looking for. I could run a CAT 5 to do this cheaper.
Thanks very much.